# Need to understand a MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql

I have this procedure from a mysql database where in a routine there is a line in a sql statement which is making no sense to me and I need to convert it to Oracle PL/SQL procedure, here is the procedure and the line is makred as bold so if you have mysql experience I will really appreciate if you can explain me how this line fits there - Thank you!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rewards_report (
    IN min_monthly_purchases TINYINT UNSIGNED
    , IN min_dollar_amount_purchased DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED
    , OUT count_rewardees INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Provides a customizable report on best customers'
proc: BEGIN

    DECLARE last_month_start DATE;
    DECLARE last_month_end DATE;

    /* Some sanity checks... */
    IF min_monthly_purchases = 0 THEN
        SELECT 'Minimum monthly purchases parameter must be > 0';
        LEAVE proc;
    END IF;
    IF min_dollar_amount_purchased = 0.00 THEN
        SELECT 'Minimum monthly dollar amount purchased parameter must be > $0.00';
        LEAVE proc;
    END IF;

    /* Determine start and end time periods */
    SET last_month_start = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    SET last_month_start = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(last_month_start),'-',MONTH(last_month_start),'-01'),'%Y-%m-%d');
    SET last_month_end = LAST_DAY(last_month_start);

    /* 
        Create a temporary storage area for 
        Customer IDs.  
    */
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpCustomer (customer_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

    /* 
        Find all customers meeting the 
        monthly purchase requirements
    */
    INSERT INTO tmpCustomer (customer_id)
    SELECT p.customer_id 
    FROM payment AS p
    WHERE DATE(p.payment_date) BETWEEN last_month_start AND last_month_end
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING SUM(p.amount) > min_dollar_amount_purchased
    **AND COUNT(customer_id) > min_monthly_purchases;** <---This is the line

    /* Populate OUT parameter with count of found customers */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmpCustomer INTO count_rewardees;

    /* 
        Output ALL customer information of matching rewardees.
        Customize output as needed.
    */
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM tmpCustomer AS t   
    INNER JOIN customer AS c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id;

    /* Clean up */
    DROP TABLE tmpCustomer;
END
```

What the customer_id has to do with min_monthly_purchase parameter which is an amount ??

```
INSERT INTO tmpCustomer (customer_id)
    SELECT p.customer_id 
    FROM payment AS p
    WHERE DATE(p.payment_date) BETWEEN last_month_start AND last_month_end
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING SUM(p.amount) > min_dollar_amount_purchased
    **AND COUNT(customer_id) > min_monthly_purchases;** <---This is the line
```

Many many thanks !!

Comment: This line says that the number of purchases by the customer should be greater than a threshold (`min_monthly_purchases`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put it this way :

```
No. 1 Parameter IN min_monthly_purchases is not an amount its a threshold which customer has to qualify to get the rewards !

No. 2 Parameter IN min_dollar_amount_purchased is the minimum amount that customer has paid to quality for the rewards !
```

Hope it make sens now !

Answer (score 1):

The person who wrote this procedure wants to find all customers that bought for an amount of money more than the minimum passed amount, and at the same time, they doesn't want it to be in one purchase but in multiple purchases, meaning that these customers should have paid more than X money in more than Y purchases, where Y is the minimum monthly purchases.

`COUNT(customer_id)` is how many times this customer id appeared in the `payments` table in the last month => it is how many purchases this customer did.

In other words these are returning and paying customers.